# Score counter error in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In the onFinish method of a timer I have, I want the user to have a point added to their score if their input is equal to a random number (LoadG1). The IDE wants me to use an array and score to final. I followed its advice to remove errors but failed to achieve my goal. I spent time trying to code it in different ways (e.g: using parseInt and ==) but received the same output. I don't get what I'd expect, and instead receive "Score: [l@fea28db".

```
public void onFinish() {
                    number.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    final TextView prompt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prompt);
                    prompt.setText(" Enter the number");
                    final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterAnswer);
                    input.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    input.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                            switch (keyCode){
                                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                                    Editable answer = input.getText();
                                    input.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    prompt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    if (answer.equals(loadG1)){
                                        score[0]++;
                                    }
                                    return true;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Here is where I output the score:

```
 public void onFinish() {
                    TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outcome);
                    result.setText("Score: "+ score);
                    TextView prompt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prompt);
                    prompt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
```

I've also tried doing `score=score+1` and `score+=1`, with not difference in output. I'd greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `score` is an array, you probably need to dereference it, looks like right now you are printing the `toString()` of an array, which isn't the value you are actually looking for.

Try doing `result.setText("Score: " + score[0]);` instead.

The IDE probably suggested using a final array because you are passing a local variable into an anonymous inner class, but wanted to change it's value and track it later. Found out more about this pattern here: [Why are only final variables accessible in anonymous class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544/why-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class) (Ivan Dubrov's answer is particularly relevant).

Comment: This helped, I had to use parseInt (String.valueof) and == for the score to actually go up. Essentially, they had to both be converted to integers for a point to be added. Your suggestion of bringing the array back at the end got rid of the weird output error and gave me a 0. Thanks for the response.